# ANTLR4 Grammar for parsing x86 Assembly

Tags: gcc, x86, antlr4, grammar

I wrote some `C++` code and compiled it to `Intel` style assembly using `g++ -S -masm=intel -O3 main.cpp -o main.S`. My issue can be reproduced with the following simple hello world program, though.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`main.S`:

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .def    ___tcf_0;   .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
___tcf_0:
LFB2024:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov ecx, OFFSET FLAT:__ZStL8__ioinit
    jmp __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    .cfi_endproc
LFE2024:
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "Hello World\0"
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB1547:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    call    ___main
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], 11
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], OFFSET FLAT:LC0
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:__ZSt4cout
    call    __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:__ZSt4cout
    call    __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    xor eax, eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE1547:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .def    __GLOBAL__sub_I_main;   .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
__GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
LFB2025:
    .cfi_startproc
    sub esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    mov ecx, OFFSET FLAT:__ZStL8__ioinit
    call    __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:___tcf_0
    call    _atexit
    add esp, 28
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE2025:
    .section    .ctors,"w"
    .align 4
    .long   __GLOBAL__sub_I_main
.lcomm __ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .ident  "GCC: (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3) 8.2.0"
    .def    __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _atexit;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Now I want to use an `ANTLR` grammar to parse the assembly code in `main.S`. I tried the one provided [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/asm8086) since it seemed promising. However, I got plenty of parse errors. Is it not meant to be used for this task? Is there any other grammar more appropriate for parsing `GCC` generated assembly?

`Parse Tree Inspector`:

[image]

`Lexer` output:

```
line 1:7 token recognition error at: '"'
line 5:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 5:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 5:8 token recognition error at: '_'
line 6:0 token recognition error at: '_'
line 6:1 token recognition error at: '_'
line 6:2 token recognition error at: '_'
line 9:22 token recognition error at: '_'
line 9:23 token recognition error at: '_'
line 10:5 token recognition error at: '_'
line 10:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 13:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 13:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 13:8 token recognition error at: '_'
line 14:17 token recognition error at: '"'
line 16:8 token recognition error at: '"'
line 16:20 token recognition error at: '\'
line 16:22 token recognition error at: '"'
line 17:24 token recognition error at: '"'
line 19:8 token recognition error at: '_'
line 20:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 21:0 token recognition error at: '_'
line 31:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 31:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 31:8 token recognition error at: '_'
line 34:34 token recognition error at: '_'
line 34:35 token recognition error at: '_'
line 35:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 35:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 36:34 token recognition error at: '_'
line 36:35 token recognition error at: '_'
line 37:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 37:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 46:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 46:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 47:0 token recognition error at: '_'
line 47:1 token recognition error at: '_'
line 52:22 token recognition error at: '_'
line 52:23 token recognition error at: '_'
line 53:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 53:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 54:34 token recognition error at: '_'
line 54:35 token recognition error at: '_'
line 54:36 token recognition error at: '_'
line 55:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 61:17 token recognition error at: '"'
line 63:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 63:8 token recognition error at: '_'
line 64:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 64:8 token recognition error at: '_'
line 65:8 token recognition error at: '"'
line 66:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 66:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 67:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 67:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 68:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 68:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 69:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 69:7 token recognition error at: '_'
line 70:6 token recognition error at: '_'
line 1:17 no viable alternative at input 'main.cpp"\r\n'
line 2:23 no viable alternative at input 'noprefix\r\n'
line 4:10 mismatched input '4' expecting {'!', EOL}
```

Answer (score 4):

Reading that grammar, and looking and the AST generated, it's easy to see that a line like `.p2align 4,,15` is matching the rule `lbl` for the token `.p2align` and that then `4,,15` doesn't match any `assemblydirective` or `instruction`.

So, **No**, that's not the grammar you are looking for.

I don't know if there exists any ANTLR grammar for gas, however the syntax is mostly (completely?) line based with directives starting with a dot.
It's easy to parse that.

If you need to parse the code too, consider using AT&T (oh boy, I cannot believe I'm saying this!) as it is made to be easily parseable.
If you want to stick with the Intel's syntax, I don't think you need a LL parser in the first place as the assembly language should be regular.
Using a simple FSM or a regex may be easier and more effective.